# How to pass a URL as a query string parameter in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

does anyone know how to pass a URL as a query string parameter and then get the URl in HttpGet method as a parameter ?

Comment: It is a string-type data. Just append it to your query, remember to remove the `http://` protocol and then it can be returned in your actions.

Comment: By "passing" do you mean embedding a URL within another URL as a parameter? If so, use HttpUtility.UrlEncode().

Comment: Yes, a lot of people know... googling for the solution shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: The main issue you will have is that you need to escape many of the characters in a uri.

Comment: Are you trying to get the previous URL or a different one?

Comment: I've tried HttpUtility.UrlEncode but still it doesn't seem to work and gives following error: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: e.x. http://localhost:54227/api/url/www.stackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f10202833%2fpassing-current-page-url-as-a-parameter-in-url                  im trying to pass the link after api/url/. basically I want to pass a url parameter to a web service and the web service httpGet method extracts the url.

Comment: `HttpUtility` no longer exists in the version of asp.net referenced; Raj's answer to his own question below is the correct one as he phrased the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks so much for all the answers. Finally I got it sorted. Please refer to my fix below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UrlController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{*longUrl}")]
    public string ShortUrl(string longUrl)
    {
        var test = longUrl + Request.QueryString;

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetUrlToken(test));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

just like this?

```
<a href="/Home/Index?url=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://stackoverflow.com")">current url with UrlEncode</a>

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string url = null)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HttpUtility.UrlEncode should do the job for you

404 might be because the application is not in running mode

host you application and try it in local it should be working as  needed

i was trying as http://localhost:11331/Home/?id=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A11331%2F

and everything is working fine even the redirection to the launch screen

or else post the complete URL you are getting so that i can help you