# Escape a value of a query param that contains the name of a param

Tags: rest, api, http, encoding, query-string

I have to call an API with a `url` param that contains `?url=` inside its value. Is there any way to escape it?

Example of a call:

https://my.api.com/delete?url=https://sidebar.io/out?url=https://css-tricks.com/

The API doesn't recognise it. Is it any way to escape this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your API see as the url? It should be escaped automatically on the call

Comment: I am not an API author. I am trying to use one — quite popular service tho. This `https://my.api.com/delete?url=` is part of an API, and this `https://sidebar.io/out?url=https://css-tricks.com/` is the value that I am trying to pass.

Comment: You need to `URL.Encode` the query string parameter before placing it inside your call. This post may help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648222/how-to-pass-a-url-as-a-query-string-parameter-in-mvc)

Comment: Passing URL as a param is not a problem here. The problem is that I am passing a value that contains the name of a param: `?url=http://example.com?url=https://example.com`.